# Как сделать возможность выбора группы картинок в ImageAdapter? Help

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, android-studio, activity

Привет, закончились мысли, пишу вам. Как в `public int getCount()` создать возможность выбора коллекции (определенной группы) картинок для галереи `Thumbslbs,Thumbslbs2,Thumbslbs3` и т.д.?

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {
    private Context mcontext;
    int j;
    public static Integer[] Thumbslbs = { R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.a2,
            R.drawable.a3, R.drawable.a4, R.drawable.a5, R.drawable.a6,
            R.drawable.a7, R.drawable.a8, R.drawable.a9, R.drawable.a10, };

    public static Integer[] Thumbslbs2 = { R.drawable.a11, R.drawable.a12,
            R.drawable.a13, R.drawable.a14, R.drawable.a15, };

    public static Integer[] Thumbslbs3 = { R.drawable.a11, };

    public ImageAdapter(Context Context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mcontext = Context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView ImageView = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            ImageView = new ImageView(mcontext);
            ImageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(115, 100));
        } else {
            ImageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        ImageView.setImageResource(Thumbslbs[position]);
        return ImageView;
    }

    @Override
    **public int getCount() {
        switch (R.id.detailsPhone) {
        case 111:
            return Thumbslbs.length;
        case 222:
            return Thumbslbs2.length;
        default:
            return Thumbslbs3.length;
        }
    }**

}
```

Comment: У вас в связке switch/case проверяются условия неверно. R.id.* это интовое значение. Напишите условие при котором должны вибираться нужные значения

Comment: @Vladislaw, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Ну... Э-э-э... Создайте переменную в адаптере и по ней отдавайте в нужном методе нужное значение...

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Можно назначить новый адаптер, передав через конструктор int, по коему отдавать нужное число в методе **public int getCount()**. В данный же момент вы делаете там выбор по неизменному числу, получая всегда один и тот же ответ. Также у вас в getView() идёт выбор картинки из одного и того же массива, а нужно выбирать из какого. Т.е. сделайте переменную класса, коя будет в конструкторе по переданному int назначать нужный массив картинок. Далее в getView() назначайте картинки из этого массива.
2. Можно сделать метод изменения массива адаптера. Т.е. передаёте в него int, по нему назначаете как в первом варианте переменной класса нужный массив и вызывайте в этом методе notifyDataSetChanged() метод адаптера. Он обновит список с уже новыми данными.

Comment: А пример можешь написать? Ибо башка не варит совсем.

Comment: @Vladislaw, обновил ответ.

Comment: Идея и состояла в том, что значение, которое было бы в R.id.text и выбирало бы нужный мне массив, но R.id.text является TextView, и при попытки его определить через findbyid он создает мне новый адаптер, а не определяет, что это TextView, в этом и вся загвоздка.


    public int getCount() {
        switch (R.id.text) {
        case 111:
            return Thumbslbs.length;
        case 222:
            return Thumbslbs2.length;
        default:
            return Thumbslbs3.length;

Comment: @Vladislaw, к сожалению я ничего не понял. Что вы хотели сделать, как это делали, чего ожидали и что получили?

Comment: При значении в TextView он же R.id.text, задается определленый масив с картинками(Thumbslbs.length), это теория,на практике
public int getCount() {
TextView textv=(TextView)findbyid(R.id.text);// находим и определяем       
text=gettext(textv).int();//преобразуем в int
switch (text) {
        case 1:
            return Thumbslbs.length;//если значение в textv равно 1 вывести
        case 2:
            return Thumbslbs2.length;
НО в самом начале findbyid, не определяет,эклипс видит ошибку, предлогает создать адаптер.надо чтобы массив картинок выбирался из значения приходящих в TextView

Comment: ВООБЩЕ СПАСИБО ТЕБЕ))) ХОТЬ ЗА ЭТО) Я КУДА УЖЕ ТОЛЬКО НЕ ПИСАЛ, И ТОЛЬКО ТУТ ПОМОГ ТЫ ХОТЬ МОРАЛЬНО